# Cannot get pinecone upsert to work in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

No matter what I am trying on my flask server, I cannot get an upsert to work. I even stopped using the document I was trying with, and have switched over to just the sample from pinecone. That works on the website itself, but not when I try via the sdk. Any help is appreciated, I am going nuts here.

```
sample_doc = {
    "vectors": [
        {
            "id": "item_0",
            "metadata": {
                "category": "sports",
                "colors": [
                    "blue",
                    "red",
                    "green"
                ],
                "time_stamp": 0
            },
            "values": [
                0.07446312652229216,
                0.8866284618893006,
                0.5244262265711986
            ]
        },
    ],
    "namespace": "example_namespace"
}

# Upsert the vector into the Pinecone index
index = pinecone.Index(index_name)
index.upsert(vectors=[sample_doc])
ValueError: Invalid vector value passed: cannot interpret type <class ‘list’>
```

Note that I have tried every possible variation on this, i’ve tried `index.upsert(sample_doc)`, variations of the insert object, etc.

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

might be your dict instead of list in the upsert method.  In addition, your namespace should be outside the list. As such:

```
sample_doc =[
              {
                "id": "item_0",
                "values": [
                    0.07446312652229216,
                    0.8866284618893006,
                    0.5244262265711986
                ],
                "metadata": {
                    "category": "sports",
                    "colors": [
                        "blue",
                        "red",
                        "green"
                    ],
                    "time_stamp": 0  } 
               }   ]  
    
    # Upsert the vector into the Pinecone index
    index = pinecone.Index(index_name)
    index.upsert(sample_doc,  namespace = "example_namespace")
```